# How to solve Non linear equation in R

Tags: r

How to solve the equation ,y=x^a in R so that we get the optimize value for 'a'.
Here y and x are (n x 1) matrix and 'a' is unknown parameter.
How to solve this in R??

Comment: Do you want to fit?  The easiest way is to take `log` for each side and get `log(y) = a * log(x)`.  The "best" `a` will be thus found by `lm(log(y) ~ log(x) - 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy with the numerical non-linear minimization function `nlm()`. You define a loss function that should be minimized. In your example that would be eg

```
f <- function(a) mean((y - x^a)^2)
```

This is a simple sum of squares loss function. You have to square the difference between `y` and `x^a`, otherwise the minimum would be `-Inf`.

Now you can just use `nlm()` to find the minimum:

```
x <- runif(1000)
y <- x^(0.8) + rnorm(1000,0,0.1)

nlm(f, p=1)
```

gives:

```
$minimum
[1] 0.01004981

$estimate
[1] 0.8033611

$gradient
[1] 6.322894e-08

$code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 6
```

So the estimate is exactly what you would think.

Other possibilities include `optimize()` for one-dimensional fitting, but for this you have to specify an interval in which to search:

```
> optimize(f, interval =c(-100,100))
$minimum
[1] 0.8033645

$objective
[1] 0.01004981
```

The more general approach would be to use the function `optim()` that allows you to minimize over multiple parameters:

```
> optim( 0, f)
$par
[1] 0.8035156

$value
[1] 0.01004981
...
```

Note that this will result in a warning. This function is not optimized for one-dimensional optimization. You can specify `method = "Brent` but then you need to set the lower and upper limits.

So tons of possibilities in R to do this :)

Comment: Thanks @Joris Meys for your valuable suggestions and i'll will try these things in R.